# Decomposing a controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controllers

In an AngularJS app, one of the controllers has accreted a very large amount of functionality and responsibility, including methods binding to events, methods to run when those events fire and methods bound to actions received from the template. How best to break this down into a more manageable size?

Comment: Use services / factories. They are great for handling repetitive tasks.

Comment: In addition to what Barth Zalewski writes, also consider directives. But I'm afraid this is the most that can be said without seeing the code!